# How to get value of variable from method another ? (vue.js 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My code is like this :

```
<script>
    export default{
        props:... ,
        data(){
            return{
                ...
            }
        },
        computed:{
            ...
        },
        methods:{
            filterBySort: function (sort){
                ...
            },
            filterByLocation: function (location){
                ...
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For example, parameter sort = lowest (on the filterBySort method)

I want display value of parameter sort on the filterByLocation

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define variable `sort` in the data, and you change it in `filterBySort` method like this: `this.sort = lowest`, same value will be available in the method `filterByLocation` as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to set it up in the data properties.

```
<script>
export default{
    props:... ,
    data() {
        return{
          sort: null,
          location: null
        }
    },
    computed:{
        ...
    },
    methods:{
        filterBySort: function (){
            console.log(this.sort)
        },
        filterByLocation: function (){
            console.log(this.location)
        }
    }
}
```